# How to best re-use the same Excel doc in all envs

Tags: excel, oracle-bi

Web ADI (App Desktop Interator)

We use an Excel xlsm (macro) spreadsheet that adds an "Oracle" button to the Ribbon tab. I'm new it but it looks like it is used to upload data on a "JE" (Journal Entries) tab to a production website Oracle URL, "https://ebscgitprod1.oracleoutsourcing.com:443/OA_HTML/".

We've written a RPA (Robot) process that performs the same steps and we would like to test this in a lower environment. Right now, when we test in the UAT environment, we skip this Upload step. I would like the RPA process to detect whether it is running in the UAT or Prod environment and upload the data to the URL that is appropriate.

I'm not sure who Excel VBA macro. It might have been our company but it looks pretty length and complicated, I'd be surprised if all that code was developed in house. (when I do a Help-> About command, it shows an Oracle Copyright for "Web ADI", so I think my assumption is probably correct.)

The macro currently hard codes the destination URL in a CONST variable. I was thinking of modifying the code to determine, based on the location of the WORKBOOK template file that is open, whether to use to the Production URL or the UAT URL. There's probably other approaches too, like modifying the Add In to present a popup and having the Robot select which environment it wants to run in.

My concern is that I have many XLSM fiels to change and I am concerned about customzing the Oracle macros because then, if we get a new version of the macro, it's a lot of maintenance to re-apply my enhancements. I don't know that there is an alternative. I thought I heard that we are getting off of Discoverer and I suspect that the Excel templates probably hardly ever change, but I'm not sure. I'm new to everything and will try to find out.

I'm just looking for design suggestions. What do you think? Is modifying the macros the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Use Fiddler to intercept and change the URL.

https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse

Comment: Wow. That's thinking outside the box. Bravo. It's a little bit like diverting a bullet after it's been shot, a bit scary but I see the advantage of not having to mess with the macro code. Looks like I saw stuff in the link to block a URL too. Are UAT BOTs and out PROD BOTs both have the same access (bad, I know) and I need to put safeguards in place too.